# Logrotate Log Rotation Intervals

Tags: magento, logging, logrotate

I want to change my logrotate.conf file to compress and save the last 14 days worth of Magento system log files. If this is set to weekly, do my settings match up or does weekly imply I only have 7 rotations available?

```
/var/www/html/var/log/system.log {
  weekly
  rotate 14
  compress
  extension log
  create 640 www-data users
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I was looking for was the maxage count. More information can be found [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html).